# Can't fetch data with react-query

Tags: react-query

On my client-side(React js), I want to fetch data from the backend. But it's not working. The output of data is undefiend.  Code Snippets

```
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/items/${id}`;
  const { data } = useQuery("data", () => axios(url));
  console.log("data", data);
```

In the backend, I am using Express js and MongoDB as databases.

Comment: How it's not working? You're getting an error or data is empty? Can you post the useQuery function?

Comment: output is undefined. and useQuery is a hook of react-query.

Comment: Try axios.get(url) or axios({url})

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a function for fetching, for example:

```
const fetchData = async (id) => {
  try {
    const URL = `http://localhost:5000/items/${id}`;
    const response = await axios.get(URL);
    return response;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Then:

```
const { data } = useQuery("data", () => fetchData(id));
```

You have to provide the id to `fetchData`